# Use google.api.field_behavior with protoc-gen-ts_proto

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers

I want to use `google.api.field_behavior` like this:

```
message PersonRequest {
  string query = 1 [(google.api.field_behavior) = REQUIRED];
  int32 page_number = 2;
  int32 results_per_page = 3;
  string name3 = 4 [(google.api.field_behavior) = OPTIONAL];
}
```

I expect the output for `name3` to be `name3?: string` but instead the generated TS is:

```
export interface PersonRequest {
  query: string;
  pageNumber: number;
  resultsPerPage: number;
  name3: string;
}
```

I compile the proto file as:

```
protoc --plugin=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts_proto \
    -I. \
    --ts_proto_out=./src \
    ./proto/person.proto
```

and inclue the `googleapi` as:

```
import "proto/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.proto";
```

Comment: Interesting question. I thought I was familiar with gRPC but this behavior is new to me. I suspect the annotations are descriptive ("should") rather than prescriptive ("must"). You don't include the `syntax` in your proto but, with `proto3` now, you can use `optional` and curiously, you can `optional string query = 1 [(google.api.field_behavior) = REQUIRED];` and this compiles using `protoc` (26.0) without warning. In Go, `optional` changes the type to `*string` (string pointer) which enables `nil` (as well as "" and beyond). Without `optional`, the Go type is `string` which is "" and beyond.

Comment: Google's API guidelines are customarily instructable [AIP-203: Field Behavior documentation](https://google.aip.dev/203) though perhaps "documentation" is the clue. It's possible that with [Protobuf Editions](https://protobuf.dev/editions/overview/) these annotations become more important.